# Next element using for loops java

Tags: java, for-loop

Very rudimentary question but I have a loop e.g.

```
List<ObjectList> = //set of values inside. 

for(Object data : ObjectList){

// how to access next element? 
// current element is accesed by 'data'. I could get the index position and then increment but is there a easier way? 

}
```

How would you get the next element/previous? I know there are iterators i can use and so on but i want to know a neat way to do it in a for loop.

Comment: make the item (objectlist) contextaware and make functions like previoius, next, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two methods for next and pervious and pass list and element.

```
public static <T> T nextElement(List<T> list,T element){
    int nextIndex=list.indexOf(element)+1;
    return list.size()<nextIndexlist?null:list.get(nextIndex);

}

public static <T> T previousElement(List<T> list,T element){
     int previousIndex=list.indexOf(element)-1;
     return list.size()>previousIndexlist?null:list.get(previousIndex);

}
```

**1)First way**

```
for(ObjectList data : objectList){
   ObjectList previousElement=previousElement(objectList,data);
   ObjectList nextElement=nextElement(objectList,data);
}
```

**2) Second way**

```
 for(int i=0;i<=objectList.size();i++){

       ObjectList previousElement=objectList.size>i-1?null:objectList.get(i-1);
       ObjectList nextElement=objectList.size<i+1?null:objectList.get(i+1);

   }
```

**3) Third way using iterator**

Answer (score 2):

You can but don't do it as the time complexity of the loop will
increase. Just use a normal loop with an `int i` looping variable.

If you still want to do it you can find the index this way:

`int index = lst.indexOf(data);`
Then `index+1` is the index of the next element.
And `index-1` is the index of the previous element.

Comment: @TheLostMind question changed ... they need previous value and next value.

Comment: Same logic would apply regardless. I know its possible via indexof, as stated but wanted to know if there a neater way to do it. Guess there is not :s

Comment: @RoryLester The neater way is to use a normal loop with an `int i` variable. The enhanced for loop is not good at all tasks.

Comment: @RoryLester make the item (objectlist) contextaware and make functions like previoius, next, etc as posted in the comments is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) isn't iterating a `List`. This,

```
List<ObjectList> = //set of values inside. 
for(Object data : ObjectList){
}
```

Should look something like,

```
List<ObjectList> al = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(ObjectList data : al){ // <-- like so.
}
```

But that won't find any data until you populate the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a "normal" for-loop, this might be, what you are looking for:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

// add some data

for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((i > 0) ? "previous Object: " + objectList.get(i - 1) : "No previous object, current is the first one.");

    System.out.println("Current Object: " + objectList.get(i));

    System.out.println((i < objectList.size()) ? "Next Object: " + objectList.get(i + 1) : "No next object, current is the last one.");        
}
```

Key aspect is, that you have to use your loop variable (`i` in this case) to access your actual elements. `i + 1` gives you the next element and `i - 1` the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you is an iterator, its used like this:

```
List<ObjectList> list= //set of values inside.
Iterator<ObjectList> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        System.out.println(iterator.previous());
        iterator.next()
    }
```

It allows you to access the next and previous objects.

Answer (score 0):

***ListIterator:***

There is the `ListIterator` which can a bit of stepping back and forth.

Mind in the code below `previousIndex()` yields -1 at the start.

```
for (ListIterator<Object> iter = objectList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Object object = iter.next();
    Object previous = objectList.get(iter.previousIndex()); // Might fail
    Object next = objectList.get(iter.nextIndex());         // Might fail
    if (iter.hasPrevious()) ... iter.previous();
}
```